# default values for primitives

Tags: java, initialization

In Java, what would a variable of type `int` hold if it was not initialized (I know that it will not let me compile if I used `x` directly before initializing)?

say, if I did:

```
int x;
```

and how about

```
int[] x;
```

Thanks

Comment: You will want to get familiar with the JLS or [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/) document since this issue and many other mysteries of Java are well and fully spelled out there.

Answer (score 7):

Instance variables will be defaulted to a 'reasonable' value. Local variables will contain garbage.

Read up on the topic [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

Answer (score 5):

for `int x` the default value would be `0`

For primitive types please refer to this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

and for `int[] x` would be `null`

Answer (score 2):

x in "int x" is automatically initialized as 0;
x in "int [] x" is automatically initialized as null, since x is actually a reference

but compiler will prompt to initialize the variable:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The local variable a may not have been initialized
    The local variable a may not have been initialized

    at initialization.main(initialization.java:6)
```

Comment: awesome, but would this change if it was inside a method?

Comment: @vtshadow Yes, default values only apply to member variables. The compiler requires that you explicitly initialize local variables since they do not have a default value.